# Reference to member variable - owner not subject to GC?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Consider the below example (code). From the `Main` function a call to `GetA` is made which returns a reference to a member variable `a` of an object `b` created in the function `GetA`. Note that after `GetA` returns we no longer have any references to the object initially referred to by the local variable `b`. Then we force a collect by calling `GC.Collect()`.

I can see the finalization code for `B` running before the final line of the `Main` method, which leads me to believe that the below code is ill-formed?

**Question:** The below code is ill-formed? If so, how come we still have access to the member `a` of the object of type `B`, even though the object is destroyed/collected?

```
using System;

class A
{
    public int x = 5;
}

class B
{
    public A a = new A();

    ~B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finalization code running for B.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static A GetA()
    {
        B b = new B(); // <- Allocate object of type B on the managed heap
        return b.a; // <- We return a (copy-of) reference to a member of B
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = GetA();

        // Force a garbage collection
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        // This works fine, but is this valid code?
        // "Owner of" a (object of type B allocated in GetA) is dead!
        Console.WriteLine("a.x = {0}", a.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: "ill-formed" what do you mean by that? A bug? .NET does not have undefined behavior like C has. You can't access "invalid" objects under any circumstances.

Comment: Yeah I meant bug. Something working if i'm lucky the GC hasn't run and if I'm unlucky the GC has run.

Comment: For the same reason that we have Hamlet, even though William Shakespeare has long ago been collected by the great GC of mortality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come we still have access to the member a of the object of type B

We don't have access to `B.a`. We have access to an object that used to be referenced by `B.a`.

The instance of `B` created in `GetA` method created a new instance of `A` and stored a reference to it in `B.a` field. This instance of `A` is a separate object, and as long as it's reachable it will not be collected.

Comment: Thanks, this explains everything.